# How do I set default compileSdkVersion / targetSdkVersion to some API level in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I create a new project in the `Android Studio` it sets `compileSdkVersion` to some `API level` which I don't like.

How do I configure it not to do it? OR at least is there any alternative to develop without this `IDE` which really sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too vague because SDK version/name is not specified  but let me try to answer;

**By default** `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are always the latest available/downloaded SDK.

So if you don't want that then simply **delete the latest SDK** and you are done.

**How to delete?**

On `MacBook, Android Studio 3.1.3`

Go to **Preferences** > **Appearance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **Android SDK** 
[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Looks like he just moved from Eclipse

Comment: delete the sdk? what are you talking it takes hell out of a time to download it again.

Comment: @vidyakumargv unfortunately yes, deleting is the only option.