# One time solution for "app is currently compiled against android-xx" repeated Android Studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

In my case i keep getting the error below everytime i build a new project in Android studio.

```
Dependency [any dependency X] requires libraries and 
applications that depend on it to compile against 
version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer 
compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.
```

I know i have to update the "compileSdk" in build.gradle but isn't there a one time solution? somewhere in android studio settings to make sdk 33 default compileSdk.

> Alternatively, I prefer a way to automatically downgrade the dependencies to version which are compatible with API 32. (I donot plan on running my apps on android 13 or publishing them, currently i am learning.)
> Is this possible as a one time solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set default compileSdkVersion / targetSdkVersion to some API level in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074592/how-do-i-set-default-compilesdkversion-targetsdkversion-to-some-api-level-in-a)

Comment: @Ricky so to make make 33 the default compileSdk, i will have to download Sdk 33? No other way? (I dont want to download unneccessary files which i wont use.)

Comment: If you want the default be 33, doesn't that mean you want to use 33? How come will it become unnecessary files you won't use?

Comment: No, I donot want to use API 33, i have no device running that. and i donot use the emulator (hardware cant handle that.) The only reason i am being froced to compile against api 33 is because android studio automatically updates the default dependencies/ libraries to latest version. And they require compileSdk to be 33. I don't even if these dependencies are being used by me, and don't know which of their older versions are compatible with compileSdk 32. And there are 6 to 8 such dependencies.

Comment: You don't need a device running API 33 to use API 33. The SDKs are always backward compatible. And developers should always use the latest API if possible since Google Play keeps updating its policy and enforcing new apps targeting the latest API every now and then.